# Compare the dates and show the values in a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdate

i have 2 test fields with from Date and to Date and a button. when the button is tapped the validation should take place  then if the valid dates are given i want the data to be displayed in the tableView.

I am very much confused on where to write this code. Either in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** or in the **IBAction** method for the button?.

if its written in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** the validation is taking place when the view is loaded.and if its written in the method where should i write the code for displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong ,

it is better to do it in IBAction and then if you are setting values , if you think you are doing them right then the only thing you need to call is :

```
["your-table-view" reloadData];
```

then it will be done i guess..

i hope this helps..

Comment: but how will it display the values in a tableView.i think we should write something in cellForRowAtIndexPath.